# Create file in network share, test, delete file, if deleted say healthy

Tags: powershell

I need a little help putting this script into ONE big loop of somekind

What i need it to do is, the words in bold is where i am stuggling

1.Open each network share, only the first level (I have called this $Dirs)

2.Create a text file in each network share, if it already exists then to write "error **and where it errored" but to contiune script**

3.To delete the file created, if it does not exists then to write "error **where it errored" but to contiune**

4.if the scripts completes (creates the file then deletes the file from each share to put standard output as "healthy" or "error" if it did not.

**So idealy the script needs to open each share, create a text file, check the text file is created, then delete the text file, once deleted and if there was no errors say "healthy"**

```
$Dirs =  "\\Share_abc\", "\\Share_def\", "\\Share_ghi", "\\Share_jkl\", "\\Share_mno"

$FileName = "DAVETEST1234.txt"

$FileExists = (Test-Path -path $WantedfileTest1)

$WantedfileTest1 = Join-Path $dir -ChildPath $FileName

#create file in share path, if file is not created write error
foreach ($dir in $dirs) {
New-Item -itemType file -Path $Dirs -Name ($FileName) -Value "Healthy" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Start-Sleep -s 5
if ($FileExists -eq $false) {Write-Host "Error"} }

#remove item created
foreach ($Dir in $Dirs) {
Remove-Item -Path $WantedfileTest1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Start-Sleep -s 5
if ($FileExists -eq $true) {Write-Host "Error"} }
```

Comment: You have everything you need in the script above; at most, you need to change your "Write-Host" statements to reflect _what_ failed. In addition, you have the process you want to follow explicitly listed in your question. You simply need to rearrange your code to follow your defined process! This will be very nearly trivial if you sit down and think about it.